# How to handle negative cases for prime check in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, primes

With regard to the "xrange" function - ("range" in Python3) what happens when I do a negative check inside a loop? In this case, a negative number could be regarded as an edge case, but always returns None. Any insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are checking if the number is negative inside the for loop. For instance if x=-3, then you are trying to run a for loop in range(2,-1) which is None. So the for loop never runs and hence returns True.

```
def isprime(x):
 if x<=0:
   return(False)
 for a in range(2,(x//2)+1):
   if(x%a==0):
     return(False)
 return(True)
```

Answer (score 0):

By it's elementary school definition, *prime* numbers are defined for positive numbers only, thus your function should return `False` for every negative number, for example:

```
def isprime(x):
    if x <= 0:
        return False
    for a in range(2, (x//2)+1):
        if x % a == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

That being said, it is possible to extend the definition (as done in some fields in math), to include negative numbers as well (for further discussion see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002459/do-we-have-negative-prime-numbers) and [here](https://primes.utm.edu/notes/faq/negative_primes.html)). In this case, for every negative number *-n*, *-n* is prime iff *n* is prime. Therefore your code could be something like:

```
def isprime(x):
    if x <= 0:   # or use any |abs| method you'd like, like numpy's
        x = -x
    for a in range(2, (x//2)+1):
        if x % a == 0:
            return False
    return True
```